# Javascript Google Maps API icon

Tags: javascript

For the last week and a half I have been tinkering with a script for my website. I slightly altered it but have hit a skills wall. It works perfectly at the moment but I would love to add a custom marker icon. I have tried loads using lots of example code but am getting knowhere. I have saved an image on my google drive at

"https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8DJ6pJV3E9FWmFiUlFTWGl5RjA"

Please can anyone show me how to incorporate it into the code below which I know works.

```js
<div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 500px; float:left;
border:1px solid black;
 "></div>

<div id="sidebar" style="height: 500px; width: 300px;
 float:left; 
    margin: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
 line-height: 30px;
 margin-top: -10px;
"></div>  

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>

var markers = [];
var map;
var infoWin;


function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });

  infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng( -33.8, 151.0), "Place 1", "Address 1", map);
  createMarker(new google.maps.LatLng( -33.8, 151.1), "Place 2", "Address 2", map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
function createMarker(latlng, name, html, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
  
    infoWin.setContent("<h3>"+name+"</h3>"+html);
    infoWin.open(map,marker);
  });

 var sideaddress = [name]

  markers.push(marker);
  document.getElementById('sidebar').innerHTML += '<a href="javascript: google.maps.event.trigger(markers['+(markers.length-1)+'],\'click\');">'+sideaddress+'</a><br>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I am using this in a wix html app. I am not sure what you are saying as this code works perfectly and just the way I need it to. The maps and markers load fine.

Answer (score 0):

You ran into same problem as I did once, you just need to host your image image locally(localhost) or anywhere on web and then use it's url to set marker url path.

If you are using chrome, use app 'Web Server' from App Store to host your project folder that includes the image as well.